# How to scrape web data of multiple pages which have different URL based on title?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping web data from the URL http://iias.ac.in/recent-publications. I have scraped the data of all titles of this page using 'rvest'. Now i have a vector which contains title of the books as

> titl_book
> [1] "Some Essays of Tagore : History. Society. Politics   "
> [2] "INVISIBLE WEBS: An art Historical inquiry into the life and death of Jangarh Singh Shyam"
> ..

Now i'm scraping data of each book for which url is based on the title of book like this
http://iias.ac.in/publication/some-essays-tagore-history-society-politics

as vector titl_book contain suffix of common url  "http://iias.ac.in" how to scrape data of all such URL in a single go.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like some data cleaning steps are required. I highly recommend `stringr` package. Here is how I would do it.

```
title_book = c("Some Essays of Tagore : History. Society. Politics",
  "INVISIBLE WEBS: An art Historical inquiry into the life and death of Jangarh Singh Shyam")

title_book_edited = title_book %>% 
  str_to_lower() %>% 
  str_replace_all(pattern = " ", replacement = "-") %>% 
  str_remove_all(pattern = ":") %>% 
  str_remove_all(pattern = "\\.")

title_book_list = paste0("http://iias.ac.in/publication/", title_book_edited)
```

I used `str_to_lower()` to convert case of string, `str_replace_all()` to replace all matched patterns and `str_remove_all()` to remove all matched patterns. And output would look like this.

```
> title_book_list
[1] "http://iias.ac.in/publication/some-essays-of-tagore--history-society-politics"                                        
[2] "http://iias.ac.in/publication/invisible-webs-an-art-historical-inquiry-into-the-life-and-death-of-jangarh-singh-shyam"
```

Visit [this official document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf) for more information. I hope you find this helpful.